# Extracting value from column A if column B is true

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe of currencies:

```
Pair   | Amount
EUR/USD| 100,000
USD/EUR| 200,000
USD/JPY|  50,000
```

If `Pair` is, for example, `"USD/EUR"`, how would I extract `Amount` into a new column, such that:

```
Pair   | Amount |Dollars
EUR/USD| 100,000|0
USD/EUR| 200,000|200,000
CHF/JPY|  50,000|0
```

I'm sure there's a nice way to do this in Pandas, but I'm a bit of a newbie with it so far.

Comment: is Pair a list or a string?

Comment: Pair is a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 
df.assign(Dollars=np.where(df['Pair']=='USD/EUR',df['Amount'],0))
Out[383]: 
   Pair       Amount   Dollars
0  EUR/USD   100,000         0
1  USD/EUR   200,000   200,000
2  USD/JPY    50,000         0
```

EDIT :

```
df.assign(Dollars=np.where(df['Pair'].isin(['USD/EUR','EUR/USD']),df['Amount'],0))

Out[830]: 
   Pair       Amount   Dollars
0  EUR/USD   100,000   100,000
1  USD/EUR   200,000   200,000
2  USD/JPY    50,000         0
```

Define a rate you want to mul `df['Rate']=[1,2,3]`

```
df.assign(Dollars=np.where(df['Pair'].isin(['USD/EUR','EUR/USD']),df['Amount']*df['Rate'],0))
Out[870]: 
   Pair      Amount  Rate  Dollars
0  EUR/USD   100000     1   100000
1  USD/EUR   200000     2   400000
2  USD/JPY    50000     3        0
```

Comment: That is a neat solution. How would I modify it for multiple conditions? If I wanted to check for both `EUR/USD`, `USD/EUR` and `USD/JPY`

Comment: @Khaine775 then you need isin

Comment: Is it possible to have different results for the different conditions stated in `isin?` For example, `isin(['USD/EUR','EUR/USD']),df['Amount']` when matched on `'USD/EUR'`, but `df['Amount'] * 2` when matched on `'EUR/USD'`, as an example. I assume it would require a different method than `isin`, such as defining two different lists with conditions and results and putting them into a `where` statement, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way of doing it with `isin`.

Comment: @Khaine775 you can build a additional column < brb

Comment: That's one way to do it, but in some circumstances I would have to multiply with the rate, and with other pairs I would have to divide with the rate, depending on the `Pair`.

Comment: @Khaine775  seems like you need do the exchange rate?

Comment: That is correct, but the dataset I'm working on is bit more complex than the one I gave as an example. In some cases it would be sufficient to multiply the `Rate` with `Amount`, but in other cases it's not, unfortunately, which is why I'm searching for a Pandas way of performing different calculations on different conditions, since a Python for loop is quite slow.

Comment: @Khaine775 as you said , your real one is more complex , without seeing that , this is all I can provided ~ sorry about that ;-(

Comment: @Khaine775 have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 4):

May not be the most elegant, but this will add the `Dollars` column

```
df['Dollars'] = df['Amount'].where(df['Pair']=='USD/EUR').fillna(0)
```

Comment: `pd.Series.where` has a second argument where you can provide the values to be used where the mask isn't `True`  `Dollars=df['Amount'].where(df['Pair']=='USD/EUR', 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) followed by [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df.assign(Dollars = lambda x: x.loc[x['Pair'] == 'EUR/USD', 'Amount']).fillna(0)
```

However, this will provide float numbers. Potentially, you need to convert that column back to int